# ShareDirectoryClient - method to check Azure File share directory exists or not in python

Tags: python, azure

I want to know before creating a parent directory in Azure file share , weather it exists or not.
The  methods list_directories_and_files  and get_directory_properties will allow only after creating the parent directory which i dont want.
Can someone help.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike other SDKs (like [`.Net`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.files.shares.sharedirectoryclient.exists?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Files_Shares_ShareDirectoryClient_Exists_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) for example), currently there is no `Exists` method in Python SDK which would have made your task easier.

What you will need to do today is call [`get_directory_properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.sharedirectoryclient?view=azure-python#get-directory-properties---kwargs-) method on your [`ShareDirectoryClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-share/azure.storage.fileshare.sharedirectoryclient?view=azure-python) object. If the operation fails with `404 (Not Found)` error, then that would mean the directory does not exist.

FWIW, You should also submit a feature request on the [`SDK's GitHub repo`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues) by raising an issue. I recently asked for a [`feature`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/21044) and the team was kind enough to include that in one of their upcoming releases.